# Redirect with parameters in PrettyFaces

Tags: jsf-2, friendly-url, prettyfaces

i have mapping like this:

`@URLMapping(id = "edituser", pattern = "/edituser/#{ id: userBean.userId}", viewId = "/faces/pages/users/editUser.xhtml")`

and i want to redirect to it from an action method, so i tried the following:

`return "pretty:edituser/" + userObj.getId();`

but it didn't work, it reloads current page, please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case something like this should work:

```
return "/faces/pages/users/editUser.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&id=" + userObj.getId();
```

Another option would be to obtain the `UserBean`, set the id property and then return `pretty:editust`. Something like this:

```
public class Whatever {

  @Inject
  private UserBean userBean;

  public String action() {

    // do something

    userBean.setUserUd( someId );
    return "pretty:edituser";

  }

}
```